# Is it possible to disable scrolling of WebView within ScrollView and instead use the parent Scroll to scroll Webview content in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, scrollview

I am working on React Native  app, with react-navigation:5.x and react-native:0.60.5.
I have to display **ScrollView** with 3 components as its children and **WebView** is one among them.
As WebView by default is scrollable (when the content is lengthier), I am seeing 2 scrolls on my screen (one of the parent and other of webview).

I want to hide/disable vertical scroll of the WebView and instead use scroll of the parent (i.e, ScrollView) to scroll WebView content. Is this possible in React Native?